# Testing memoization

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have an expensive method called `calculate_total`. I need a method called `total` that will return the result of `calculate_total`. Subsequent calls to `total` should return the previous result of `calculate_total`.

I want to do this in a test driven way. Here are my tests (I'm using RSpec):

```
describe Item do
  describe "total" do
    before do
      @item = Item.new
      @item.stub!(:calculate_total => 123)
    end

    it "returns the calculated total" do
      @item.total.should == 123
    end

    it "subsequent calls return the original result" do
      previous_total = @item.total
      @item.total.should equal(previous_total)
    end
  end
end
```

This is not a good test because the following method makes the tests pass, but I was expecting the second test to fail:

```
def total
  calculate_total
end
```

The reason is `calculate_total` returns a `Fixnum` so ruby doesn't see the result as 2 different objects. I was expecting the second test to fail, so then I could do the following to make it pass:

```
def total
  @total ||= calculate_total
end
```

Anyone know a better way to test this?

I don't think this is the best/correct way to test it, but I've settled on this: https://gist.github.com/1207270

Comment: Do they have the same _____id_____ as well?

Comment: Yes. So, from what I'm seeing, my test can't tell the difference between, say, 1+2+3 and 6

Comment: Hmm, maybe it caches those. What I'd you explicitly create a new Fixnum, or create a wrapper around it? May not be worth it except as an exercise, not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your gist is fine: what you want to test is whether or not calculate_total is called more than once, and that's exactly what you're doing.  The only difference I might suggest is a *slightly* more explicit test:

```
it "subsequent calls don't calculate the total, but still return the original result" do
  @item.should_receive(:calculate_total).once
  2.times do 
    @item.total.should == 123
  end
end
```

Comment: Now my question is: what if calculate_total isn't a public method :)

(I generally don't like to put message expectations on private methods)

Answer (score -1):

You could call it twice in the same spec and compare the returned objects to make sure they are equal:

```
it "should memoize it" do
  total = Item.total
  # second call will yield a different object if not memoized
  Item.total.should == total
end
```